# connect mongodb with flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I want to connect my flask app with Mongodb cloud but when I run it, it shows an error at **line(44, if condition) in verify function** where mongodb code starting to execute.
Here is my code and it return

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for
import smtplib # for send message to mail
from random import randint # to generate random number
import re # for email validation
import pymongo # for connect with database
from pymongo import MongoClient
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

myclient = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://xxxxxx:Xxxxxx12@ashish-hbjy0.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
mydb = myclient.emailverify  # database name
mycol = mydb["otp"]  # table name


app = Flask(__name__)
randotp = randint(1000, 9999)   # Random 4 digit OTP Generator
otp = randotp

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/verify', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def verify():
    global email, otp
    if request.method == 'POST':
        info = request.form
        email = request.form.get('email')
        if info.get('email', None) is not None:
            if email in [temp['email'] for temp in mycol.find({}, {"_id":0, "email":1})]:  # at here it stuck
                global msg  # alreay verified message
                msg = "Email Already Verified"
                return render_template('status.html', result = email, message=msg)
            else:
                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 
                s.starttls() 
                s.login("vacancykey123@gmail.com", "@vacancyKey1")                
                otpmessage = "Your OTP " + str(otp)
                s.sendmail("vacancykey123@gmail.com", email, otpmessage)
                print("sent mail")

                #mycol.insert_one({ "email": email})
                print("email entered!")
                s.quit()
                return render_template('verify.html', result = info)


@app.route('/status', methods=['POST','GET'])
def status():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        sentotp = int(request.form.get('otp'))
        semail = email
        if sentotp == otp:
            mycol.insert_one({ "email": email})  # at here it stuck
            msg = "Email Verified"
            return render_template('status.html', email= semail, message = msg)
        else:
            msg = "Wrong OTP, Please check again!"
            return render_template("status.html", message = msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

How I solve this, I think it basically here is a problem in the connection in the mongodb cloud database with flak 
When I connect it with my localhost mongodb it execute successfully.

But it generate `ServerSelectionTimeoutError` when I connect it with mongodb cloud.

Comment: can you please give the full error stack from terminal?

Comment: i found some issues from your mongodb connection string,first one is you didn't put port on the end of the hostname also `ashish-hbjy0.mongodb.net` is not accessable at all.

Comment: Have you set up a whitelist in Atlas. By default, remote access is disabled.

Comment: yes, I did and connect successfully thanks #Belly Buster

Comment: so the problem was just a setting in the Atlas cloud.